# How to identify foreign key in MySQL DB?

Tags: mysql, database, foreign-keys

How to identify foreign key in MySQL DB Table?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/innodb-foreign-key-constraints.html

SHOW CREATE TABLE tbl_name;

You can also display the foreign key constraints for a table like this:

SHOW TABLE STATUS FROM db_name LIKE 'tbl_name';